# AKKA FileIO Stream Parsing to Newline & EOF

Tags: scala, parsing, akka, newline, eof

I am using Akka FileIO (in scala) to create a file parser that is meant to read each line from an input file and apply a simple sink. Each line is delimited with a newline ('\n') character except for the final line in the file which ends with an EOF.

How can I handle both newline and eof delimiting so that I can reliably read the final line without having to depend on a final '/n' character?

```
    var rowNum = 0
    val simpleMsgSink: Sink[String, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach {
        case row: String => {
          println(s"$rowNum: $row")
          rowNum = rowNum+1
        }
      }
    val source = FileIO.fromPath(file, 1 * 1024 * 1024 )
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 1024))
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .runWith(simpleMsgSink)
```

If this is executed against the file (no newline at the end of last line):

```
Sensor_ID,Location,Seqno,gwrx.time,Temp,Humidity,Noise,CO2,Water
A0890,"51.645368, 0.072211",1,42793.00278,16,48,36,325,0
A0891,"51.645370, 0.072300",1,42793.00278,15,41,34,353,3
```

The output is:

```
0: Sensor_ID,Location,Seqno,gwrx.time,Temp,Humidity,Noise,CO2,Water
1: A0890,"51.645368, 0.072211",1,42793.00278,16,48,36,325,0
```

How can I pickup that last line?

Comment: Thanks for testing it, @chunjef. I am also running 2.4.16. Does the snippet return 3 rows of output? Are you sure you didn't add an extra \n at the end of the 3rd line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [scala doc](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Framing.scala#L28-L33) of `Framing.delimiter`, you will see that it actually has third parameter: `allowTruncation` with default value being `false`. Here's what scaladoc says about it:

> If `false`, then when the last frame being decoded contains no valid delimiter this Flow fails the stream instead of returning a truncated frame.

So all you have to do to is add the missing parameter:

```
Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 1024, allowTruncation = true)
```

Comment: That is perfect! I had already started down the path of marking it 'false' and trying to catch an error but allowTrunction = true does just want I want. Thanks!